# Box histograms in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm not sure what these are called but can I make "box histograms" such as those shown below in R? If so, could someone please advise how I go about making them/direct me to a page with some info regarding how to code them?

[image]

Comment: `geom_dotplot` would be one option

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/barplot/) gallery contains some interesting material for you. For instance [grouped barplots](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/211-basic-grouped-or-stacked-barplot/):

```
#Create data
set.seed(112)
data=matrix(sample(1:30,15) , nrow=3)
colnames(data)=c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(data)=c("var1","var2","var3")

# Get the stacked barplot
barplot(data, col=colors()[c(23,89,12)] , border="white", space=0.04, font.axis=2, xlab="group")

# Grouped barplot
barplot(data, col=colors()[c(23,89,12)] , border="white", font.axis=2, beside=T, legend=rownames(data), xlab="group", font.lab=2)
```